# Subsetting an array with another array of indexes

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

Suppose i have a (list | np.array) `a` of size `(N,)` and a (list | np.array) `l` of integers between 0 and N-1.

Is there a way i could write more efficiently `sum([a[x] for x in l])` ?

Four different conditions:

- `a` is a numpy array, `l` is a numpy array
- `a` is a numpy array, `l` is a list
- `a` is a list, `l` is a numpy array
- `a` is a list, `l` is a list

Answer (score 1):

- a is a numpy array, l is a numpy array
- a is a numpy array, l is a list

For both of the above you can do `a[l].sum()`

- a is a list, l is a numpy array
- a is a list, l is a list

For these last two, your options are either to cast `a` to numpy and then do as above:

```
np.asarray(a)[l].sum()
```

or if you are going to use something like your list comprehension, then at least use a generator expression instead - there is no need to build a list simply to add up the values:

```
sum(a[x] for x in l)
```

If you are looking for a single solution that you can use regardless of the type, then `np.asarray(a)[l].sum()` (as suggested above) will work, because if the argument to `np.asarray` is an array anyway, then it will simply use it as-is -- but be aware that if `a` is a list then this will need to create an array version of `a`, so use of the generator expression will be more economical on memory.

```
import numpy as np

a_list = [10, 11, 12]
l_list = [2, 2]

a_array = np.array(a_list)
l_array = np.array(l_list)

for a in a_list, a_array:
    for l in l_list, l_array:
        print(np.asarray(a)[l].sum())
```

gives:

```
24
24
24
24
```